# feature concatenation tf.concat(x, tf.square(x), axis=1) fails for a placeholder x

Tags: tensorflow

If I try

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1,2,3]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = tf.concat([x, tf.square(x)], axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: x_data})
```

it fails. I basically want to make a vector [[x],[x^2]]. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.concat` can only be used to concatenate tensors along dimensions that *already* exist. If you want to concatenate tensors along a new dimension you can use `tf.stack`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1,2,3]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = tf.stack([x, tf.square(x)], axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: x_data})
```

Comment: Another option is to use `tf.reshape()` to add an extra sized-1 dimension to each input, and then to use `tf.concat()`.

Comment: @PeterHawkins Yes, if you really want use `tf.concat` you can use `tf.reshape` or simply `tf.expand_dims`.